# How to get the number of specific rows

Tags: r, row

I have two matrix:

```
A <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b"
)))
B <- structure(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("c", "d"
)))
```

and I fund the number of the rows in A that contain the first "1":

```
a_1 <- t(as.matrix(max.col(t(A) == 1, "first")))
```

and it return  "4 , 3".
Now I need to know the number of the rows in B that contain the first "1", after the rows I got as output from A ("4" and "2" respectively). The result I expect is "5" for the first col of B and "NA" (or something like that) for the second.
How can I do? Thx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
sapply(seq_along(a_1), \(i) {
  k =which(B[,i]==1);k[which(k>a_1[i])][1]
})
```

Output:

```
[1] 5 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
apply((row(B) >c(a_1)[col(B)]) * B, 2, \(x) which(x==1)[1])
 c  d 
 5 NA
```

Comment: Thx! I edited the question whit different requests

Comment: @ros_ber can you specify the logic for getting `NA`

Comment: @akrun, you don't seem to be leveraging `a_1`

Comment: "NA" because there isn't "1" in the second col of B after the third row